# Find all positions in a NumPy array that contain a substring (most efficient?)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, substring, where-clause

I want to find all indices in an array that contain a substring, in this case it is `substring = "contig_"`.  I started iterating line by line and then iterating through each element in the array but that is the most brute force as it gets.

**Are there any functions in numpy or scipy that could allow for this that are faster than brute force methods?**

```
A = np.array([['K00180:55:H3NHMBBXX:7:1101:30340:1068', '83',
        'contig_1758_2278_4341_-', '1487', '60', '140M', '=', '1334',
        '293', "=",
        '*', 'RG:Z:RG_0', 'MD:Z:23A30A85', 'NM:i:2\n'],
       ['K00180:55:H3NHMBBXX:7:1101:30340:1068', '163',
        'contig_1758_2278_4341_-', '1334', '60', '87M1I3M1D17M', '=',
        '1487', '293', "contig_1297_3232_198298_+",
        '*', 'RG:Z:RG_0', 'MD:Z:31G3G2G6T6C6A9C4T15^G17', 'NM:i:10\n'],
       ['K00180:55:H3NHMBBXX:7:1101:28026:1103', '83',
        'contig_1281_415_1704_-', '514', '60', '142M', '=', '396', '260', "=",
        '*', 'RG:Z:RG_0', 'MD:Z:11C130', 'NM:i:1\n']], 
      dtype='<U149')

for row in A:
    print(np.where(["contig_" in x for x in row])[0])

# [2]
# [2 9]
# [2]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`np.char` is a group of functions that apply string methods to the elements of an array like yours.  So using the `find` function:

```
In [311]: np.char.find(A, 'contig')
Out[311]: 
array([[-1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

-1 for the elements where it was not found, 0 or larger for finds.

```
In [312]: np.where(np.char.find(A, 'contig')>=0)
Out[312]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 2, 9, 2], dtype=int32))

In [313]: A[_]
Out[313]: 
array(['contig_1758_2278_4341_-', 'contig_1758_2278_4341_-',
       'contig_1297_3232_198298_+', 'contig_1281_415_1704_-'], 
      dtype='<U149')
```

Functions like this have to iterate over the elements, and apply the corresponding string method, so they aren't as fast as the usually numpy numeric code, but they are a lot easier than doing your own iteration.

---

`np.vectorize` or `np.frompyfunc` can also be used to apply a function to each element of an array.  They too iterate, so aren't significant speedups over your own iteration.  Still I have found that `frompyfunc` often provides a 30% speedup.

```
In [331]: f=np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x.find('contig'), 1,1)  # like char.find

In [332]: f=np.frompyfunc(lambda x: 'contig' in x, 1,1)  # your 'in'

In [333]: f(A)
Out[333]: 
array([[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True,
        False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=object)

In [334]: np.where(f(A))
Out[334]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 2, 9, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: Wow, incredible answer.  I knew numpy had to have something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s answer, I used some of the code to one-hot encode all the columns of a dataset in Pandas. This is because the `pd.dummies()` will not let you encode data as shown in the example below.

A common problem in Pandas is searching for the indices where some value A is in a column B. Though, this is further complicated when that column B is an array of strings, e.g. `B = ["Drama", "Comedy", "Thriller"]`. We want to match all rows where A is in the array of column B.

Normally, if we were not dealing with arrays as features, we could instead check for the indices where the string equals the row and column by `df.loc[df[col] == 'Drama', col]`.

**NOTE:** `count_unique` is a dictionary of features, but could just as easily have been `df.columns`.

```py
for key in count_unique.keys():
    values = np.zeros(df.shape[0], dtype=bool)

    # get indices where current key in column
    f = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: key in x, 1, 1)
    true_indices = np.where(f(df[col]))[0]
    
    # set the indices where the key does exist and create column
    values[true_indices] = True
    df[f"{prefix}_{key}"] = values
```

Note that this code is also blazing fast. We could easily have iterated through all rows with `df.iterrows()`, but we instead choose the efficient route.

**Another bad solution (apply with loc):**

We have an id column here that we need, and we also assume that there have been created empty columns, e.g. columns `col_Drama`, `col_Comedy` and `col_Thriller`. We still have a column B with values A as referenced before.

```py
def distribute_suffixes(x):
    for suffix in x[col]:
        df.loc[df['id'] == x.id, f"{prefix}_{suffix}"] = True

_ = df.apply(distribute_suffixes, axis=1)
```

It simply takes way too long to search the dataframe like this for every suffix.